# Block or Module Template for Moodle

Tags: block, moodle

I want to create a simple module for my Moodle but it takes so much time. Is there any template that I can just optionally change it and make it how I want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a boilerplate block template for Moodle, however there is a pretty decent walkthrough on the Moodle Docs page for blocks:

> To define a "block" in Moodle, in the most basic case we need to provide just four PHP files. Remember, in this example we are creating a block called 'simplehtml', replace 'simplehtml' with the name of your custom block. The four files should be located in blocks/simplehtml and are:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#Ready.2C_Set.2C_Go.21

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/danielneis/moodle-block_newblock

Provides a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from simplehtml block contributed by moodle.

https://moodle.org/plugins/view/block_editablecontenthtml

You can find detailed dev explanation here:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks